# vlc: open one instance when started from file?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, vlc

I just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. The way vlc opens files has been broken in the process, and doesn't work how I want anymore.

Now it seems I can't open multiple files in one instance, it instead opens multiple instances. What I would like is the following:

- ability to have multiple vlc instances
- if I open multiple vlc files at once from the file manager, just open one new instance with all the files selected
- if I open one file from the file manager, and then another file, it should open two instances.

Note that the vlc option 'Use only one instance when started from file manager' breaks requirement #3.

I'm sure this is possible, I had it working before (I think it's the file manager that did it for me, but it doesn't work anymore).

Comment: Just disable both `Allow only one instance` & `Use only one instance when started from file manager`

Comment: @doug this breaks requirement #2

Comment: #2 says multiple files "at once", I see no issues there, works fine here with the settings disabled. How are you opening multiple files at once?  Typical would be shift + click to highlight  > right click > open with vlc

Comment: @doug Well then I must have a problem, because it doesn't work in my case. Can you please help me to figure out what's breaking it for me?